# undefined method `variety_id' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `variety_id' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

When i'm adding the <%= r.results.variety_id %> code to my trial view. The <%= r.site.site_name %> works fine, but can not work out why the <%= r.results.variety_id %> won't work. The Results database has many trial_id's (3-6) that I want to match against the Trials database and then list them on my trial view.

Trial view

```
<% @results.each do |y| %>
<h1><%= y.year %> Trials</h1>
<% end %>
<hr>
<% @results.each do |s| %>
<h3><%= s.site.site_name %></h3>
<% end %>
<hr>
<% @results.each do |r| %>
<%= r.results.variety_id %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def trial
  @results = Trial.where(params[:trial_id])
end
```

Models

```
class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :trial_id, :site_id, :year

  scope :year, ->(year) { where(year: year) }
  scope :trial_id, ->(trial_id) { where(trial_id: trial_id) }

  belongs_to :site, :primary_key => 'site_id'
  has_many :results

end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :trial_id, :variety_id, :year

  belongs_to :trial

end

lass Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :site_id, :site_name, :region

  has_many :trials

end
```

Schema

```
 create_table "results", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "trial_id"
    t.integer  "variety_id"
    t.string   "year"
  end

  create_table "sites", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "site_id"
    t.string   "site_name"
    t.integer  "region"
  end

  create_table "trials", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "trial_id"
    t.integer  "site_id"
    t.string   "year"
  end
```

The trial_id columns in results and trials a pre populated with corresponding id's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Trial` class `has_many :results`, so when you call `r.results.variety_id`, you are trying to call the `variety_id` method on a group of results, not just one. Try using an iterator, such as `<%= r.results.map{|r| r.variety_id} %>`.

Alternatively, you could loop through the results using another each block and display the `variety_id` of each one:

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
  <% r.results.each do |result| %>
    <%= result.variety_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```